# Passing Variable from NodeJS to client-side JS file

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to pass a server-side JavaScript variable to a `<script>` tag in an HTML view?

In my routes file I have:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/index.html', {
      data: {foo: bar}
  });
};
```

If I was using a Jade template, I could do:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

To access the `data` object. However, that doesn't work for an html file. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a route send the data using `res.json()` and use AJAX in the html to fetch the JSON data.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: If you want something more similar to Jade you would probably have to put a placeholder in the HTML then parse the HTML and replace the placeholder with the variable value then send it, but at this point why not just use Jade?